# What functions satisfy the product of their derivatives being equal to their product

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $$\frac{\frac{d}{dt}x(t)}{x(t)} =\frac{y(t)}{\frac{d}{dt}y(t)}$$

How would we go about proving solutions other than $x(t)=y(t)=e^{t}$ exist, and furthermore if we could prove other solutions exist could we determine what they are?

Is there a general form for:
$$\frac{\frac{d^n}{dt^n}x(t)}{\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}x(t)}\frac{\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}y(t)}{\frac{d^n}{dt^n}y(t)}$$

Comment: You have also $x=Ce^{at}$ and $y=De^{(1/a) t}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g = \frac{y'}{y}$. Then the differential equation is
$$\frac{x}{x'} = \frac{1}{\frac{d}{dt} ln(x)} = g$$
And so $$x(t) = ce^{G(t)}$$ is the family of solutions to this differential equation, where $G(t)$ is an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{g(t)} = \frac{y}{y'}$. Indeed, solutions of this forms are the only ones. Your last equation would have a similar result, since one can just replace $x$ and $y$with their $(n-1)^{th}$ derivatives.

Comment: Good solution. Perhaps add that you are on an interval $I$, that $y$ is $C¹$ on $I$ and that the derivative of $y$ is never $0$ on $I$, hence your $1/g$ has an antiderivative.